# SSL: Issued SSL for www.domain.com but only works for https://domain.com

Tags: ssl, domain, ssl-certificate, hosting

Last week about an SSL Certificate issued by RapidSSL and my hosting MediaTemple, you can see the order details at RapidSSL here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3APN.jpg

And SSL details on my panel at MediaTemple here:

[image]

I bought the certification for `www.domain.com` but it only shows for `domain.com` (without the www).

Any thoughts about this? How can I change this? I really need it to work with www - Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is unclear. From the order details shown on the imgur link you posted, nothing looks wrong. The certificate common name and SAN would ensure that authentication should work with or without the 'www'. I say "would" because you didn't show us the actual certificate, which is the only important thing.

Comment: That's the issue, nothing looks wrong, and apologise I've never manipulated SSL certificates, my first time and I'm no expert. I don't know if it's okay to share the RAW certificate? (THE -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- [....] -----END CERTIFICATE-----)

Comment: What do you mean with `it only shows for`? What do you get when you visit `https://www.domain.com`?

Comment: @jornane The page breaks (SSL connection error "It wasn't possible to establish a secure connection with the server") - "with only shows for" I mean that it only works for the domain without the "www"

Comment: That isn't very helpful. Which certificate do you get when you go to `https://www.domain.com`? Is it your certificate, or another one?

Comment: Only the private key is, you know, private. The certificate contains the public key (not the private) and is thus not secret. It will, however, contain the domain name which you changed to `domain.com` for the sake of this question, so you would be releasing that information if you share the certificate.

Comment: Got it. Your `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` point to different IP addresses. The IP behind `www.domain.com` does listen on port 443 but doesn't do a valid handshake.

Comment: @jornane is there anyhting I can do about it? or anything I can investigate to fix it? I really need to fix this since is an ecommerce website where transactions will occur. Thank you

Comment: Looks to me that there's something CloudFlare going on. The IP behind `www.domain.com` points to CloudFlare, the other one points to Mediatemplate. I know too little about your setup to be able to give you real pointers, other than that you should talk to support. But if you want HTTPS support via CloudFlare, you'll probably have to talk to them (and pay them?)

Comment: @jornane Yeah did I set up Cloudflare using MediaTemple's one click installer. I'm not really on budget to buy a new SSL, do you recommend me to remove Cloudflare in order for it to work? Thank you

Comment: Disabling CloudFlare could help, but, again, I know too little about your setup to be sure about anything. If you got CloudFlare via MediaTemplate, i'd suggest you talk to MediaTemplate support. We can't help you here, as this has to do with their systems, not with server management. I wish you luck.

Comment: @jornane thank you for your help, I had no idea what it had to do with, really appreciate :)

Comment: @jornane sorry how did you checked if the IP was pointing to Cloudflare? Already disabled Cloudflare but still not showing (Maybe it will take a while)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you that you must cancel the order and order new certificate with new CSR and it must contains the www. version domain name.

RapidSSL offers www and non-www support when you generate certificate for www veresion, so cancel your current order and re-issue your certificate with new CSR.

Comment: You didn't look at the picture and didn't read the comments. The certificate is correct, the `www.` version of the domain was hosted by CloudFoundry and didn't present the (correct) certificate.